# Making feature layer based on attributes (2 columns) in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, layers, select-by-attribute

I'm new to Python, but know this tool can solve my problem. I have a large dataset and I want to extract layers based on the attributes of two columns.

For example, my dataset has columns A-N. In this exercise, columns D and C are of relevance. These columns both have variables ranging from 1-9. I want to loop through this data set and extract every combination based on these two columns (D=1 and C=1, D=2 and C=1, D=1 and C=2, etc.).

I assume I need to use a combination of the 'select by attribute' tool and 'make a feature layer' tool, but am having trouble putting together the two.

Can you provide a basic script structure for this solution?

Comment: Dissolve them using these 2 fields.

Comment: Make feature layer is temporary; do you want a more permanent extract?

Comment: @TVEC_GIS Do you know the values for C and D in advance, or do you need to determine this from the dataset during the loop?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an untested and very dirty method that uses itertools.permutaions to generate a where clause for every combination of values for fields C and D (if they are integers 1-9 and don't contain null values).  Since there were a bunch of details not explained I just took a guess.  Sorry if it's not what you are looking for.  I am also not sure of the where clause statements validity.

```
import itertools, arcpy

#if the only values available in both coloumns are a integers 1-9
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

#generates a list of lists for every combination of the two fields
possibleCominations = [x for x in itertools.permutations(numbers, 2)]

out_path = "pointFeatureTest.gdb"

#builds a list of the where clauses
where_clauses = []
for combo in possibleCominations :
    where_clauses.append("D = {D} AND C = {C}".format(D=combo[0],C=combo[1]))

lyr_name = 'featureClass'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (in_features, lyr_name)
for whereClause in where_clauses:
    #formats the where clause so that it can be used as the feature class name
    fc_name = whereClause.replace(' ','_').replace('=','eq')
    print fc_name
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion (lyr_name, out_path, fc_name, where_clause = whereClause)
```

I have not tested this and did it from memory so I don't guarantee it to work.

Also,  you could change it so that the where clause is with the arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management and then get a count with arcpy.GetCount_management before exporting so that you aren't exporting an empty feature class if the combination of C and D doesn't  exist.  Like below:

```
 import itertools, arcpy

    #if the only values available in both coloumns are a integers 1-9
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    #generates a list of lists for every combination of the two fields
    x = [x for x in itertools.permutations(numbers, 2)]

    out_path = "pointFeatureTest.gdb"

    #builds a list of the where clauses
    where_clauses = []
    for list in [x for x in itertools.permutations(list1, 2)]:
        where_clauses.append("D = {D} AND C = {C}".format(D=list[0],C=list[1]))

    lyr_name = 'featureClass'

    for whereClause in where_clauses:
        #formats the where clause so that it can be used as the feature class name
        lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (in_features, lyr_name,where_clause = whereClause)
        if int(arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr).getOutput(0)) > 0:
            fc_name = whereClause.replace(' ','_').replace('=','eq')
            print fc_name
            arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion (lyr_name, out_path, fc_name)
        #cleanup
        del lyr
```